# Downloading Pdf into Subdirectory

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the PDFs to download into a subdirectory using the form name so it should look like Form W-2/Form W-2 2020. Currently, it just downloads to the same folder as the main app.

```
        pdf_link = form_number.find("a")
        i += 1
        print("Downloading file: ", i)
        response = requests.get(pdf_link.get('href'))
        pdf = open(form_number.text.strip() + "-" + form_year.text.strip() + ".pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response.content)
        pdf.close()
        print("File ", i, " downloaded")
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join path components, [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if directory exists and [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create the directory.

This example combines the methods:

```py
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

form = "Form W-2"
URL = (
    "https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication."
    "html?resultsPerPage=200&sortColumn=sortOrder&indexOfFirstRow=0&criteria=formNumber&value="
    "" + form + "&isDescending=false"
)
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for table_element in soup.select(".picklist-dataTable tr:has(td)"):
    form_number = table_element.find("td", class_="LeftCellSpacer")
    u = form_number.a["href"]
    path = os.path.join(form, u.split("/")[-1])

    if not os.path.exists(form):
        os.makedirs(form)

    print(f"Saving {u=} to {path=}")
    with open(path, "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(u).content)
```

Prints:

```
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1990.pdf' to path='Form W-2/fw2p--1990.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1989.pdf' to path='Form W-2/fw2p--1989.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1988.pdf' to path='Form W-2/fw2p--1988.pdf'

...and so on.
```

and saves the documents to directory.

---

EDIT: To save with different filenames:

```py
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

form = "Form W-2"
URL = (
    "https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication."
    "html?resultsPerPage=200&sortColumn=sortOrder&indexOfFirstRow=0&criteria=formNumber&value="
    "" + form + "&isDescending=false"
)
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for table_element in soup.select(".picklist-dataTable tr:has(td)"):
    form_number = table_element.find("td", class_="LeftCellSpacer")
    form_year = table_element.find("td", class_="EndCellSpacer")
    u = form_number.a["href"]
    p = "{}-{}.pdf".format(
        form_number.get_text(strip=True), form_year.get_text(strip=True)
    )

    path = os.path.join(form, p)

    if not os.path.exists(form):
        os.makedirs(form)

    print(f"Saving {u=} to {path=}")
    with open(path, "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(u).content)
```

This saves the files as:

```
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1990.pdf' to path='Form W-2/Form W-2 P-1990.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1989.pdf' to path='Form W-2/Form W-2 P-1989.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1988.pdf' to path='Form W-2/Form W-2 P-1988.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1987.pdf' to path='Form W-2/Form W-2 P-1987.pdf'
Saving u='https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw2p--1986.pdf' to path='Form W-2/Form W-2 P-1986.pdf'

...
```

Comment: My only problem is I'm trying to save the pdf in the format that is Form W-2/Form W-2 - 2020.pdf. How would I do that?

Comment: Good approach! but take care when you download those files more than once, each file will be overridden so it'd be better to make a condition before writing using: `if not os.path.exists(path):`